# json_array_elements: invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have the following sample data for demo:

**Table**:

```
create table tbl_json
(
   id json
);
```

Some values:

```
insert into tbl_json values('[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]');
```

**Query**: Convert/cast `id` into `integer` from json column.

**Tried**:

```
select json_array_elements(id)->>'id'::int ids 
from tbl_json;
```

Getting an error:

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "id"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::int` cast is applied to `'id'` because it has a higher precedence.

```
select (json_array_elements(id)->>'id')::int ids 
from tbl_json;
```